# Form submit data to database and to url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I need to submit a form to a url for processing, and also insert the form fields to a database. The form is standard HTML, and the action is currently set to :

```
<FORM name = "HTML_FORM" METHOD=POST ACTION="https://urlhere/MRcgi/ProcessIncomingForms.pl">
```

My first thought was to change the action to a custom php page,which would

1. Send the data to the above script
2. perform the insert into DB.

**But - and this is my question- not sure if they can be done and how to do- in sequence??**

Note: I dont have access to the ProcessIncomingForms.pl script, and I dont think this will matter but, the form fields don't match the database fields, so I will also have to do reassignments before I can submit into the database. Ex:

```
$help_user = $_POST['username'];
$help_dept = $_POST['help_dept'];
```

Comment: Save the form data using `ajax` then submit your form another url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the action as you suggested, then on the new php page insert into the db as normal then create a form and submit it for the user:

```
<form action='https://urlhere/MRcgi/ProcessIncomingForms.pl' method='post' name='frm'>
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."'>";
}
?>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure I get this line:echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."'>"; Does that need to be done for each form value?

Comment: That is, for each form input on the original form, there is a associated name ($a) and value ($b). We are outputting each of these into a hidden form field. This results in a form containing the exact fields and data that the original form contained, but now on our new php page rather than the original. We can then submit this form after doing any additional processing. We are basically transparently forwarding the POST request to ProcessIncomingForms.pl

Comment: Ah, ok. So if there are ten fields...? Sorry I am being dense.

Comment: Then the foreach will run 10 times each time outputting one of the original fields.